# Не отображаются гугл карты (Серый экран)

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps-api

[image: Серый экран смерти 0_o]

Есть сайт с Joomla, есть раздел, где должны отображаться карты. Вместо этого только оверлей и серый экран. Поставил в родители #img значение max-width:none;
Не помогло. Надеюсь, получится решить этот вопрос. Заранее спасибо за любой ответ!

Comment: Посмотрите, может в консоле есть записи об ошибках?

Comment: @Zelta,Нету к сожалению :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если есть элементы управления - значит карта грузится (проблема не с доступом к гуглу). Следовательно вопрос только в подгрузке самих тайлов, возможно нет доступа к определённому серверу, и/или настройки клиента блокируют. Для этого надо глянуть со стороны (другой браузер, режим инкогнито), а лучше с другого компа. Сам сейчас копаюсь с гуглкартами, скинь ссылку гляну.

Comment: можем в ВК обсудить?Буду признателен